# Problem with "save and continue editing" in Craft CMS

Tags: craftcms

i have some weird behaviour in my craft installation.
It came after some update not sure when.

The problem is when i use "save and continue editing" button (or shortcode) then i'm redirected to wrong url. Post / Asset is saved but i'm redirected to not existed page.

example:
init url:
`http://mydomain.test/admin/assets/myCompanyMedia/204885-bird-gf3c26a528_1920?site=default`

url after save: `http://mydomain.test/admin/%EF%BB%BFhttp://mydomain.test/admin/assets/myCompanyMedia/204885-bird-gf3c26a528_1920?site=default`

Is anybody know where i can start looking?

Answer (score 0):

Are you facing the same issue with other entries like page navigation etc?
Have you tried creating the new post or any new assets what does it do then?

Comment: i have this problem for any assets.

I also have this problem for other sections but only for old one. If i create new entry then the problem does not occur.

In the case of assets, it does not matter whether it is old or new.

Comment: Have you migrated your website?
 This could be a migration issue and for assets check your ASSETS_BASE_URL and ASSETS_BASE_PATH

Comment: thank you for response.

Nope. There was no migration. Here are my env settings:
`RAFTENV_BASE_URL="http://mydomain.test/" ASSETS_BASE_URL="http://mydomain.test"`

Comment: Thanks for the information what about the ASSETS_BASE_URL settings?

Comment: you mean in .env file? this is how it is set: `ASSETS_BASE_URL="http://mydomain.test"`

But this is also happens for some Entries. So i'm not sure is this about assets url at all.

Comment: This could be different then you can give it a try and check your logs if you find any error log there.